# Comments menu to display separately on php while loop using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, class, loops

So first and foremost,, not really that good with javascript, so I've been stucked here for a while. Will appreciate any help.

I have a comment system built with php, where each comments from the database has an ID and I'm displaying all of them on a page using a while loop. Problem is, the each have this 3-dot menu on them where a user can edit, delete, report and the likes of it. But I can't seem to get them to display individually. I have only succeeded in getting the first to display, no matter the comment I click on, the menu just displays on the first one. Or it displays all at once when I use a querySelector. But my motive is to get each to display separately for each comment. This is my Lil novice code.

```
if(isset($_POST['allReviews'])){
    $product_id =$_POST['product_id'];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE product_id='$product_id'";
    $check = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($check) > 0) {
        $n=0;
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($check)) {
            $n++;
            $product_id = $row["product_id"];
            $rating = $row['comment_rate'];
            $rate_comment =$row['u_comment'];
            $user_id = $row['user_id'];
            $prefix = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/Hostels';
            ?>
                <div class="comments">
     <div class="user_pic"><img src="<?=$prefix?>/img/prof.png" alt="user pic"/></div>     
       <img src="<?=$prefix?>/img/unlike_empty.png" class="unlike" alt="thumbs up">
       <img src="<?=$prefix?>/img/like_empty.png" class="like" alt="thumbs up">
       <img src="<?=$prefix?>/img/dots.png" onclick="ShowMenu()" class="my_menu" alt="dots"/>

       <ul id="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" class="comment_menu">
         <li><a class="edit">Edit</a></li>
         <hr style="width:120%;margin-left:-38px;">
         <li><a class="delete">Delete</a></li>
         </ul>
    <div class = "comments_body">
         <?php echo $rate_comment; ?>
     </div>
    </div>
<script>
function ShowMenu() {
           var y=document.querySelectorAll(".comment_menu");
            for(var i = 0, ilen = y.length + 1; i < ilen; i++){
             y[i].style.display = y[i].style.display =="block"? "none":"block";
</script>
    <?php
 }
  }
   }
    }

     ?>
```

Please let me know if you need me to show the full code plus the php while loop.. I'll do so. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put up more of your code for us to be help you better.

Comment: Okay,, let me do just that

Comment: Done... Thanks alot for the reply..

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able test the code but I think this will work.  Pass $user_id to javascript function to change display property like this.

```
<img src="<?=$prefix?>/img/dots.png" onclick="ShowMenu(<?=$user_id?>)" class="my_menu" alt="dots"/>

<script>
function ShowMenu(thisId) {

    var x = document.getElementById(thisId);
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        // hide already shown menu
        var y=document.querySelectorAll(".comment_menu");
        for(var i = 0, ilen = y.length + 1; i < ilen; i++){
         y[i].style.display = y[i].style.display ==="block"? "none":"block";
        }
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }

}
</script>
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks alot.. I'll let you know if it does. Thanks again

Comment: Didn't work.. Stopped the menu from showing completely.. Maybe I'm doing something wrong..??

Comment: I need to see rendered HTML. So using  browser's 'view source' functionality, copy 2 or 3 <div class="comments"> ... Then it will make things more clear to me.

Comment: Using Ajax to load the page, and this is shown on the action.php file, the view source functionality will only show an empty div.. Which I'm filling with Ajax.. But let me try to take it back into the comments div then.. I'll re-edit once I get that sorted.. Thanks. I appreciate